# is it safe to overwrite __setitem__ on an appengine polymodel?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, magic-methods, polymodel

I'm making a spam filter library for google app engine, which uses app engine hooks to modify some data right before it is `put()` into the datastore. To do so, I created a model that subclasses the PolyModel class, which classes wishing to be checkable should subclass.

But for some data in the class, I'd like to do some stuff when the value is changed, for which I'd have to overwrite `__setitem__`. But I believe the sdk uses this to determine changes in the properties of models, apply filters etc, and so changing overwriting `__setitem__` might break this. What's the best way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no danger in overriding methods, if you don't forget to call the parent method with `super`. But in your case `__setitem__` is wrong place, because then everytime when instance is created it will be cleaned from spam, even if it is created from already cleaned values.

What is wrong if you do that explicitly?

```
filter_out_spam(obj)
obj.put()
```

Comment: the explicit model would work indeed, but I'm trying to make it automatic. See it as a centralization. If the user wants to add this to their app, they only need to edit one piece of code, instead of prepending this to all put() calls.

Answer (score 2):

Don't modify `__setitem__` - write a [custom property class](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Custom-Datastore-Properties-1-DerivedProperty) that does what you want, instead.

Bear in mind that you can't just override `put` on your model if you want to do things before the record is put, because entities can also be stored with `db.put`. If you can, you should avoid the need for this by moving the relevant code into property classes.

Comment: I'm not overwriting put, I'm using a hook which is called by the sdk every time a request to the dtabase is made. I check wether the action is 'put', and then do my stuff to the model.

Comment: @FrederikCreemers Fair enough. My advice about not overriding the model's `__setitem__` still applies.